# MySQL nested SELECT query is taking too long to run

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query I wrote that displays the data I want it to, but it takes at least 30 secs - 1 min to run.

I researched to find out how to created the nested `SELECT` query with the `COUNT` that I needed in order to display the data I required. The SQL is also part of a web page I have, and when I go from page to page it takes the same amount of time to load. I am sure there is a more efficient way to write the query so it loads fast, as there are only about 1,500 records in the **ttb_shows table** and about 11k in the **ttb_books table**. Below is the query.

```sql
-- DDL
CREATE TABLE `ttb_books` (
  `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `book_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cover_image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `show_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `state_id` int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notes` text,
  `year` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `publisher` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_id` int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `no_pages` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `footer` text,
  `opt1` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '$5-10',
  `opt2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opt3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opt4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opt5` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owned` int(1) DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `ttb_shows` (
  `show_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `show_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- QUERY
SELECT ttb_shows.show_id, ttb_shows.show_name, ttb_shows.date_added,
    COUNT(ttb_books.book_id) AS books,
    (SELECT COUNT(ttb_books.owned) AS owned FROM ttb_books WHERE (owned=1 AND ttb_books.show_id = ttb_shows.show_id)) 
FROM ttb_shows LEFT JOIN ttb_books ON ttb_shows.show_id = ttb_books.show_id 
GROUP BY ttb_shows.show_id, ttb_shows.show_name, ttb_shows.date_added
```

Thank you to all who are able to help with this. It is really appreciated!

Comment: You should add structure of the two tables used in the post as well, so we can at least have a bit more info in order to help you identify the problem.

Comment: co-related subqueries which `SELECT COUNT(ttb_books.owned) AS owned FROM ttb_books WHERE (owned=1 AND ttb_books.show_id = ttb_shows.show_id)` tends to run badly in MySQL without indexes... As it runs like nested loops without indexes..

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results as most likely that query can be rewritten as a JOIN instead.. Also for provifing table striuctures which @AwesomeGuy requested use `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved the query.. As this is a performance question we also need to have `EXPLAIN query` output..

Comment: Have you tried auditing your query? Try executing `EXPLAIN <QUERY>` where `<QUERY>` is your query to see what is causing your query to be slow.

Comment: table structures added for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could avoid the subquery for owner using sum based on case

```
SELECT ttb_shows.show_id
  , ttb_shows.show_name
  , ttb_shows.date_added
  , COUNT(ttb_books.book_id) AS books
  , sum( case when  ttb_books.owned = 1 then 1 else  0 end) AS owned 

FROM ttb_shows 
LEFT JOIN ttb_books ON ttb_shows.show_id = ttb_books.show_id 
GROUP BY ttb_shows.show_id, ttb_shows.show_name, ttb_shows.date_added
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I didnt even know about sum and case. Thanks for the insight and help!

Comment: @Aaron  your are welcome ..  the use of condition sum (or aggreagation function) is often used  in sql

Answer (score 0):

Your query can be optimized by you only. It seems that so many left outer will obviously slow the output. If you can either avoid so many left outers or make small chunks of cases to fetch out data and then fetch the Final output.